# mysqli_connect() : No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/example.php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lampp

Whenever i run the code in localhost:

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'connection not valid';
    }else{
        echo 'connection successfull';
    }
?>
```

I keep getting a warning, stating that there is no file in directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/example.php

I'm currently running zorin(debian based), and installed xampp through the apache friends website's installer. I have apache2, and have installed php5-mysql, along with mysql-5.5, mysql-client, mysql-server, and apache2.

when i open xampp's index.php file it says "something is wrong with the xampp installation :-(".

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: `mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword","db");`? - Plus, are you accessing your file using `http://localhost/index.php"` or `file:///index.php"`?

Comment: localhost/index.php, and yeah, forgot to add that what i meant was 'mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword", "test")'